# "Explain" VS "Describe"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I wonder how the following verbs differ the meaning of my self-made sentence:

> 1. Let me **explain** to you how it happened.
> 2. Let me **describe** to you how it happened.

To me, both of the sentences above mean the same thing; although, I know that "describe" mostly calls for "sensory experiences" and "explain" calls for "analysis", but still I don't know how can I interpret them as different concepts for myself.
Please let me know how would you understand them?

Answer (score 2):

**Explain** is about causes and motives.  **Describe** is just about events.

Imagine a policeman finding out what happened.

Policeman: Please **describe** what happened.
Witness: I saw the man slap the woman on the back.

Policeman to man: Please **explain** what happened.
Man: I was trying to kill a mosquito.

Comment: Well @jonathanjo, could you possibly provide me with some more explanations?

Comment: What does the man mean by "Man: I was trying to kill a mosquito."? :-?

Comment: A mosquito lands on the woman's back.  The witness **describes** seeing the man slap the woman on the back.  The man **explains** he was trying to kill the insect, not hit the woman.

Comment: Basically, "explain" is "why", and "describe" is "what".